# error handling using winston not returning response

Tags: node.js, winston

I am using winston error handling in Node.js application

```
var logConfig={
    level:'info',
    timestamp:true,
    colorize:true,
    handleExceptions=true
};
logger = new (winston.Logger)({
    transports: [
  new (winston.transports.Console)(logConfig)
]
  });      
}    
logger.exitOnError=false;
```

Apart from logging I want to use the error handling feature of winston. It is an express app

I can see winston handles the error properly, prints the stacktrace and prevents the server from crashing, but the response never come back to browser. Is there a way to specify this behavior?

Thanks

Comment: try posting that as an issue on the project's Github: https://github.com/flatiron/winston

Comment: what exactly do you mean by "the response never came back to browser"? What does your app do after the logging takes place? Do you return an error in the response?